How to calculate the exact space deleted in a MongoDB collection
I have a example collection called events in MongoDB, the total uncompressed size was 14.3 TB and occupied size in disk is 4.2 TB. Recently i have deleted few documents and reduced the disk size from 14.3 TB to 3.1 TB but the storage size remains same as 4.2 TB.
I want to know the actual storage size got deleted or the current exact storage size.
Am using MongoDB 4.2 and i guess from 5.0 we have field called freeStoragesize added in collection.stats() command.
please suggest
Example collection stats
{
    "ns" : "events.events",
    "size" : 3425712836056,
    "count" : 327198795,
    "avgObjSize" : 10469,
    "storageSize" : 4640121118720,
    "capped" : false,
    "wiredTiger" : {
        "metadata" : {
            "formatVersion" : 1
        },



I want to know the actual storage size got deleted or the current
exact storage size.

If you wish to know the size that got deleted, you can make use of compact command along with db.collection.stats() and perform some calculations among them to get deletedStorageSize.
Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Cannot run compact here as data size is huge and requires time to complete.
is there any other query or command to run and find the same ? we got the exact field in version 5.0.0 onwards
